# Mac, git: Why might I be getting an app/package when git cloning from Bitbucket instead of a directory?

Tags: git, macos, bitbucket

Using standard git clone. `git clone <path-to-package>`

The only thing in the repo is a .gitignore, and other people have been able to clone it no problem.

Other repos have cloned just fine. I've tried multiple times.

Is it because the repo is called `nostradamus.prediction.service`? The others are named like `nostradamus.dataset.generator`, so maybe the term `service` has something to do with it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's just a mac thing:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15298/why-does-os-x-prevent-access-to-a-folder-if-it-ends-with-the-word-service/15303

Don't end your directories with a `.service`!

Comment: That is the stupidest thing.....